# AWS API Gateway CORS pre-flight check fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway

I'm using Zappa to deploy my application, cors is enabled and everything seems to work OK when pressing the "test" button on the options in API Gateway "OPTIONS" resource.

However, when I try to do the CORS pre-flight check, I get a 500 error with body `{"message": "Internal server error"}` and CloudWatch logs `Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to transform request`

**EDIT**:

This is what the configuration looks like:[image]

**EDIT 2**
I've tried enabling the CORS by both via `zappa_settings.json` (`"cors": true`) and by manually clicking enable cors in the AWS console

Does anyone have any pointers how to debug this further?

Comment: Did you accidentally added any configuration to Method Request or Integration Request for OPTIONS?

Comment: You might have an issue with the mapping template. Have you tried to debug it locally?

Comment: Did you tried something more? It's the problem solved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Does anyone have any pointers how to debug this further?*

I have some things:

In your `zappa_settings.json`, you don't have this option  `binary_support: false`, right?

Because:

> You can leave cors: true but set binary_support: false - they don't
>   appear to be playing nicely together.

([here](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/699) have the same problem and solved removing binary support)

If no, you can try this:

- In OPTIONS method, choose as integration type "mock"
- For each Method of a resource
- Go to Response Method
- Add all the response method that should be supported (i.e. 200, 500, etc.)
- For each response code set Response Headers to:

  > X-Requested-With
  >
  > Access-Control-Allow-Headers
  >
  > Access-Control-Allow-Origin
  >
  > Access-Control-Allow-Methods
- Go to Integration Response, select one of the created response codes, then Header Mappings
- Insert default falues for headers
  example:

  > X-Requested-With: '*'
  >
  > Access-Control-Allow-Headers: 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,x-requested-with'
  >
  > Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'
  >
  > Access-Control-Allow-Methods: 'POST,GET,OPTIONS'
- This operation has to be repeated for each method, including the newly created OPTIONS
- Deploy the API to a stage
- Check using http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client that CORS requests have been successfully enabled

*(extracted from [here](https://enable-cors.org/server_awsapigateway.html)).*

I assume that you already checked this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html ...

I also found this to be considered, cited from [here](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/494):

> It should also be noted that simply enabling CORS at the API gateway
>   layer is necessary but not sufficient for an application that wants to
>   do CORS requests against a Zappa API that is IAM authenticated (and
>   likely authenticated using other API-gateway level authenticators).
>   The application itself will still need to respond with the appropriate
>   CORS related headers, but it doesn't get the opportunity to do that if
>   API Gateway blocks the pre-flight request.

Hope it helps to you!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your OPTIONS method is using a mapping template.
Is that intentional?

If so, please post the template.

If not, then try re-running the CORS wizard from the API Gateway console to reset your CORS configuration.

Also, remember to re-deploy your latest changes before you test with the browser.

Comment: No, no mapping template. Also have tried and retried running the CORS wizard dozens of times...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a whole lot about zappa (we use [serverless](http://serverless.com) at the moment for managing lambdas and API gateways), but I noticed your `OPTIONS` Method Response is bound to a Model for `Content-Type application/json`.

Our config seems to be working ok, with no associated Models at all - IIRC OPTIONS shouldn't have a body in the response. I wonder if having the Model defined is adding a body - even though you've configured an *Empty* body.