# PUT call not working for s3 bucket using a AWS GATEWAY api?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3, axios, aws-api-gateway

admin:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at '/dev/directjobfinder/listing.json' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

**IT'S WORKING FINE IN POSTMAN BUT WHEN IM USING AXIOS.PUT THEN IT'S GIVING THE ABOVE ERROR SOMEONE PLEASE HELP I'M STUCKED FROM LAST 2 DAYS**

I HAVE DONE Access-Control-Allow-Headers : * Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *'

CORS CONFIG file of S3 bucket
`[ { "AllowedHeaders": [ "*" ], "AllowedMethods": [ "GET", "PUT" ], "AllowedOrigins": [ "*" ], "ExposeHeaders": [] } ]`

EDIT :
[ERROR DETAILS SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN8xc.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my http://localhost CORS origin not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/why-does-my-http-localhost-cors-origin-not-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER : I was calling the api using axios and my method was POST but the problem was in the response header , I was passing a javascript object as application/json , there resides the problem itself i just change it to tex/plain then it works fine .

Answer (score 0):

[CORS config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cors.html) on the S3 bucket should allow `OPTIONS` method for a preflight request.

Comment: [
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "Origin",
            "Content-Type",
            "Action"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
CORS config for s3 bucket , I'm not able to add OPTION in allowedMethods
Found unsupported HTTP method in CORS config. Unsupported method is OPTIONS

Comment: for option Found unsupported HTTP method in CORS config. Unsupported method is OPTION

Answer (score 0):

make sure OPTIONS returns 200 ok by running the curl command.

```
curl -X OPTIONS -H "Origin: ORIGIN_URL" --verbose API_ENDPOINT
```

If not then run the below command

```
aws apigateway update-integration --rest-api-id YOUR_REST_ID --resource-id YOUR_RESOURCE_ID --http-method OPTIONS --patch-operations op='replace',path='/contentHandling',value='CONVERT_TO_TEXT'
```

and dont forget to redeploy the API

for more details:
[AWS API gateway error while making OPTIONS request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55667066/aws-api-gateway-error-while-making-options-request)